# Tar --exclude $VAR

Tags: linux, bash, sh, tar

I'm coming after a lot of tries, a lot of reading on the internet and I can not find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to script a backup and I have a command to tar the folder, but the --exclude refuse to work.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
Folder1/
---- Folder2
--------- Folder3
-------------- Folder4 -> ../../Folder1 (Symlink)
```

The idea is create a tarball of the Folder2, including the files from Folder1 using a symlink (Folder4) but excluding the symlink to avoid a loop. So in the bash file I have this:

```
ln -s $Folder1 "$Folder2/$Folder3/Folder4"

EXCLUDE="'$Folder2/$Folder3/Folder4/$Folder2'"
tar --exclude=$EXCLUDE -cJhv backups | gpg2 --passphrase 'foo-bar' | ssh somwhere@space "mkdir -p /$BACKUP_NAME/finished-backups ; cat >  /$BACKUP_NAME/finished-backups/$BACKUP_FILE_NAME_AND_PATH.gpg"
```

The bash file generate this, and if I run directly on the terminal works like a charm:

```
tar -cJhv --exclude="Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder2" Folder2  | gpg2 --batch  --passphrase "foo-bar" | ssh root@somewhere "cat > /root/test_stream/result.tar.xz.gpg"
```

But when I'm running it on the file, the tar is not excluding the Symlink folder.

Cheers.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the `-h` option of the `tar` command?

Comment: Because Folder 4 is a symlink and I want to backup the content of the folder that is symlinked, not keeping the symlink.

All this is done because I don't want to copy and store the content of the backup in the server.

Comment: It works just fine here: minimal test case: `mkdir -p /tmp/test/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3 && cd /tmp/test/Folder1 && ln -s ../.. Folder2/Folder3/Folder4 && echo foo > bar && tar -cvhf - --exclude 'Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder2' Folder2 > /dev/null`  The symlink structure "drawing" in your example seems to be wrong though.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Finally I've figured it out, it was a problem of relative paths, as tar exclude need to use path inside the path you are taring, I've changed to this:

`EXCLUDE=""--exclude='$Folder2/$Folder3/Folder4/$Folder2'"
tar $EXCLUDE -C Folder2 -cJhv Folder2 | gpg2 --passphrase 'foo-bar' | ssh somwhere@space "mkdir -p /$BACKUP_NAME/finished-backups`